# IIS 7.0 Application Pool identities can only use pre-Windows 2000 account names?

Tags: iis-7, iis

I've been troubleshooting the inability to assign a certain username as the identity for our App Pool running on an IIS 7 installation.  The account used has a name that is 24 characters long, and regardless of how I checked to make sure it was correct I would always get an invalid password error when I tried to set up an account.  However, when I supply the Pre-Windows 2000 name of the account (essentially truncating the username down to the first 20 characters) I am able to use the account.

What am I missing to be able to make it so I can just use the full username?  While this method would technically work, I'd like to resolve the issue if possible for the sake of a homogenous environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't waste time on it. Assume it's a bug, and use the SamAccountName. UPNs are pretty so users can remember them; App Pools tend not to make their username visible to anyone but the admins...